# stuck on CS50x left aligned to right aligned mario pyramid

Tags: cs50

I have been trying to make my pyramid from left aligned to right aligned but i am confused on how to do it. This is the code i am using. 
Edit: i have changed the code but i have been getting an error

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
 {
    int height;
    do
{
    //asks user for number between 1 and 8
        height = get_int("please give height: ");
}
    while (height < 1 || height > 8);
    //prints rows (i)
    for (int rows = 0; rows < height; rows++)
    {
            //prints spaces (j)
        for (int spaces = 0; spaces < height - rows; spaces++)
       {
            printf(".");
       } 
             printf("\n"); 
          }

          for (int hashes = 0; rows < height - rows; hashes++)
            {
                printf("#");
            }
                printf("\n");

 } 



user gets prompted and writes number between 1 and 8
user types 4

Expected
...#
..##
.###
####
    Actual output
....
...
..
.


mario.c:24:48: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rows'
          for (int hashes = 0; rows < height - rows; hashes++)
                                               ^
mario.c:24:32: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rows'
          for (int hashes = 0; rows < height - rows; hashes++)
                               ^
2 errors generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'mario' failed
make: *** [mario] Error 1
```

i am trying to print hashes and use the rows interger but for some reason the error says it is am undefined interger.

Comment: What are your actual results?  What do you expect to have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make the pyramid (CS50 Mario Program) formed by this code to be right aligned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32303244/how-to-make-the-pyramid-cs50-mario-program-formed-by-this-code-to-be-right-ali)

Comment: @CacahueteFrito my current results are
#
##
but i want it as 
 #
##

Comment: @FossilBone In the comment we can't see the difference.  Please, add it to our question.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito i have fixed it

Comment: You should print spaces (`' '`) before printing the `#`s, inside the `i` loop. I leave it up to you to decide how many.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Ive been getting a new error about an undefined integer

Comment: That for loop is outside of the main for loop.  If you had proper indentation you would have noticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is because you're curly brackets {} in your first and second for loops are mixed up.  It looks like you're trying to do three loops that are nested inside each other; however, your third loops is outside the first one because you have an extra } in the middle of your code for the second loop.  The variable row is declared in the first loop and the third loop doesn't know what that means since it is outside the first loop.

Sticking to the class's recommendations about indentation helped me keep this straight.